# Cant get my list to print out correctly with commas

Tags: c

I'm trying to get my program to find if a number is prime if it isn't then list out what the number is divisible by

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, j, k = 0, c = 0;

    printf("Enter an integer between 1 and 1000 (inclusive): \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n > 1000 || n < 0) {
        printf("You must enter a number between 1 and 1000 (inclusive).\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0) // check divisible number from 1 to n
            {
                c++; // count the divisible numbers
            }
        }
        if (c == 2) // c is 2 the number is prime
            printf("%d is prime.", n);
        else
        {
            printf("%d is divisible by ", n);
            for (i = 2; i <= 31; i++) // first 11 prime numbers
            {
                k = 0;
                for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (i % j == 0) //i=(2,3,7,11,13,17,19,23,31)
                    {
                        k++;
                    }
                }
                if (k == 2)
                {
                    if (n % i == 0) //if i prime number. n is divisible by i or not
                    printf("%d", i);
                    if (i < 5)
                    {
                        printf(", ");
                    }
                }
            }
            printf(".");
            printf("\n%d is not prime.\n", n);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Currently, when I enter 62 it outputs

62 is divisible by 2, , 31.

But when I attempt to change the if(i < 3) statement than it'll mess with other printings such as trying with 468 it'll print out

468 is divisible by 2, 313.

Comment: Why did you choose such a long strange solution? You could solve it inside the first `for` loop. If the remainder is zero, print the divisor.

Comment: The current code block: `printf("Enter an integer between 1 and 1000 (inclusive): \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n > 1000 || n < 0) {
        printf("You must enter a number between 1 and 1000 (inclusive).\n");
    }`  is very convoluted and gives the user only one chance to get it right.  Suggest:  `do {
        printf("Enter an integer between 1 and 1000 (inclusive): \n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    while( n > 1000 || n < 0 );`

Comment: Note:  given `n` the max number that needs to be checked is `sqrt(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. does not check for I/O errors
3. performs the desired functionality
4. makes use of the Variable Length Arrays feature of C

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, c = 0;

    do {
        printf("Enter an integer between 1 and 1000 (inclusive): \n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while( n > 1000 || n < 0 );

    int divisors[n];

    divisors[ 0 ] = 0;
    divisors[ 1 ] = 0;

    for ( int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) 
        {
            divisors[ i ] = i;
            c++; // count the divisible numbers
        }
        else
            divisors[ i ] = 0;
    }

    if ( !c ) 
        printf("%d is prime.", n);

    else
    {
        printf("%d is divisible by ", n);
        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if( divisors[i] )
            {
                printf( "%d ", i );
            }
        }

        printf(".");
        printf("\n%d is not prime.\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following runs are with the values supplied by the OP

```
Enter an integer between 1 and 1000 (inclusive): 
62
62 is divisible by 2 31 .
62 is not prime.

Enter an integer between 1 and 1000 (inclusive): 
468
468 is divisible by 2 3 4 6 9 12 13 18 26 36 39 52 78 117 156 234 .
468 is not prime.
```

Answer (score 1):

The posted code, first tests the given number against each number up to itself, counting the number of divisors, only to determine if it's prime. If it's not, then it somehow (with a lot of magic numbers) recalculates those factors and tries to print them as requested.

It would be easier to calculate the primes (once) and the list of factors first, storing them in some arrays and only then generate the desired output.

You can produce the same output while calculating each factor by keeping at least track of the number of factors already printed, if any.

In that case, I'd change the algorithm into something like this

```
// The orignal number will be consumed, divided by all of its factor.
int m = n;
int count = 0;

// Start from 2, the first prime, up to the last number less or equal to the sqrt(m).
for (int i = 2; i <= m / i; ++i)
{
    // Check if what is left of the original number is divisible.
    if ( m % i  ==  0 ) 
    {                
        // Cunsume the number. E.g: 81 % 3 == 0  =>  81 -> 27 -> 3 -> 1
        //                          24 % 2 == 0  =>  24 -> 12 -> 6 -> 3
        do
        {
            m /= i;
        }
        while ( m != 1  &&  m % i == 0 );

        // Here, we can add the print logic and update the count of divisors
        if ( count == 0 )
        {
            printf("%d is divisible by %d", n, i);  // <- First factor
        }
        else
        {
            printf(", %d", i);                      // <- I-th factor
        }
        ++count;
    }  
}

if ( count == 0 )
{
    printf("%d is prime.\n", n);
}
else
{
    if ( m != 1 )
    {
        printf(", %d.\n", m);                      // <- Last prime factor
    }
    puts(". It's not prime.");  // 'printf(".\n%d It's not prime.\n", n);' if you prefer
}
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k6yzpNy1c95LMPAg).

Answer (score 0):

The way of printing was the problem. It found `2` and printed out `2,`. It found `3` and printed out `3`, then it found `13` as the last divisor. From this you got `2, 313` as output.

I modified the part when the number is not a prime:

```
        int first_divisor = 1;
        printf("%d is divisible by ", n);
        for (i = 2; i <= 31; i++) // first 11 prime numbers
        {
            k = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0) //i=(2,3,7,11,13,17,19,23,31)
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if ((k == 2) && (n % i == 0))
            {
                if (first_divisor == 0)
                {
                    printf(", ");
                }
                printf("%d", i);
                first_divisor = 0;
            }
        }
        printf(".");
        printf("\n%d is not prime.\n", n);
```